# How do I go back to an older version of chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

chrome apps recently stopped working with controller support and I need it to complete a project that I have been working on 
I am using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/robotopen-ds/bhpgaibglpbnkhlkmpjhfmlpfbolgkme?hl=en-US
controller support recently broke with the latest update to chrome and I need to be able to use it.
I am using a logitech f710 to use it and it is working with html5

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a Google Chrome offline installer for installing any previous versions of Chrome and stop it from getting updated. You can find the direct links to download the offline installers from [here.](http://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php)

After the installation, you need to stop it from auto-updates too, you can see [How to disable Google Chrome auto update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483087/how-to-disable-google-chrome-auto-update)

In case the above discussion doesn't help, you can follow the steps given in this [link.](http://www.wikihow.com/Completely-Disable-Google-Chrome-Update)

Hope this solves your problem.